# How to fit a scalable Bayesian VAR model in Stan/JAGS

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, vector-autoregression, jags, stan

I am trying to fit a Bayesian vector auto regressive model but I am struggling with the computation. I tried both JAGS and Stan to fit the model but I have never been able to fit it successfully. It either takes days and I have to stop the run or it ends up not converging after if finished the run. Here is the model:

```r
library(rstan)
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())

#Simulating toy data: 

T     <- 400
alpha <- 1
gamma_1 <- 1
gamma_2 <- 0.4
sigma <- y <- rep(NA, length = T)
set.seed(123)
sigma[1] <- runif(1)
y[1] <- 0
for (t in 2:T) {
  sigma[t] <- sqrt(gamma_1 + gamma_2 * (y[t - 1] - alpha)^2)
  y[t] <- rnorm(1, mean = alpha, sd = sigma[t])
}

df <- data.frame(t1 = y, 
                   t2 = y, 
                   t3 = y, 
                   t4 = y, 
                   t5 = y, 
                   t6 = y, 
                   t7 = y,
                   t8 = y,
                   t9 = y)

############### Stan code #####################
model_code <- "
data{
  int<lower=1> T;    //Time
  int<lower=2> K;    //location
  matrix[T,K] y;     //Target time series
}
parameters {
  vector[K] alpha;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
  matrix[K,K] theta;
  row_vector[K] mu_t1 ;
  
}
transformed parameters {
  matrix[T,K] epsilon;   //Residuals
  matrix[T,K] mu;        //Mean of the process
  mu[1,] = mu_t1 ;
  epsilon[1,] = y[1,] - mu[1,];
  
for (t in 2:T){  
   for(k in 1:K){
    mu[t,k] =  alpha[k] + theta[k,] * epsilon[t - 1,]';
    epsilon[t,k] =  y[t,k] - mu[t,k] ;
  }
 }
}
model{
  //priors
for(k in 1:K){  
  alpha[k] ~ normal(0,3);
  for(j in 1:K){
  theta[k,j] ~ normal(0,1);
  }
}
mu_t1 ~ normal(7,1) ;
sigma ~ normal(0, 5);
for(k in 1:K){
  for (t in 1:T)
    y[t,k] ~ normal(mu[t,k], sigma);
          }
}
"

model_data <- list(
  T = nrow(df), 
  K = 8,
  y = df
)

stan_run <- stan(
  data = model_data,
  model_code = model_code,
  iter = 20000, 
  chains = 4
)

############### JAGS code #####################

model_code <- "
model
{
  # Likelihood
  
   for(k in 1:K) {
      for (t in 1:T) {
                     y[t,k] ~ dnorm(mu[t,k], sigma[t,k]^-2)
                     error[t,k] <- y[t,k] - mu[t,k]
  }
  
  sigma[1,k] <- sigma_1
  mu[1,k] ~ dnorm(0, 100^-2)
  
  for(t in 2:T) {
              mu[t,k] <- A[k] + Phi[k,] %*% error[t-1,]
              sigma[t,k] <- sqrt( a_1[k] + a_2[k] *   
  pow(sigma[t-1,k], 2) )
      }
   }
  
  # Priors
  for(k in 1:K) {
  
   A[k] ~ dnorm(0, 100^-2)
   a_1[k] ~ dunif(0, 10)
   a_2[k] ~ dunif(0, 1)
    for(j in 1:K) {
    
   Phi[k,j] ~ dnorm(0, 1^-2)
   
      }
  }

  
}
"

df_JAGS <- as.matrix(df)

# Set up the data
model_data <- list(T = nrow(y), K = 8, y = df_JAGS, sigma_1 = sd(df$t1))

# Choose the parameters to watch 
model_parameters <- c("mu", "Phi", "A", "sigma")

# Run the model
model_run <- jags(
  data = model_data,
  parameters.to.save = model_parameters,
  model.file = textConnection(model_code))
```

I need to be able to fit the model to at least 8 time series (each having 400 observations). Does anyone know if this is possible to do or simply MCMC is not cable of handling such big/complex problems?